# Total distance travelled using integrals

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

- For time $t \geq 0$, the velocity of a particle moving along the $x$-axis is given by $\mathrm{v}\left(t\right) = \sin\left(t\right)$, where $t$ is measured in seconds and $\mathrm{v}\left(t\right)$ is in meters per second.
- The initial position of the particle at time $t = 0$ is $x = 8$.
- What is the total distance the particle traveled from time
  $t = 0$ to $t = 2\pi$?

So, I tried solving this by doing
$\int_{0}^{2\pi}
\left\vert\sin\left( t\right)\right\vert\mathrm{d}t$, in which I got $2$, but the answer is wrong.

I suspect it's something to do with the $t = 0$ and $x = 8$ but I don't know how to use that in this context.

Comment: Is the answer $4$?

Comment: Your integral is wrong.

Comment: @ares the question is asking for distance moved, not displacement

Comment: You should integrate between $0$ to $\pi /2$ and then multiply by 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $Sin (t)$ has symmetry about $\pi/2$ and its range is positive between $(0,\pi)$ and negative between ($\pi,2\pi$), you should integrate between $0$ and $\pi / 2$ and then multiply by 4. The question is about distance and not displacement.

Comment: why would we multiply by 4? and I get that the question is about distance, but isn't the formula for the distance the definite integral of the absolute value of the function?

Comment: You will multiply by 4 as you will get the same distance between ($0,\pi / 2$), ($\pi / 2, \pi$), ($\pi, 3 \pi / 2$), ($3 \pi /2, 2 \pi$).

Comment: $Cos 0^0$ to $Cos \pi / 2$ is 1, so is each of the range.

Comment: You will get much better visual results if you use LaTeX/MathJax symbols `\sin` and `\cos` for trigonometric functions instead of normal text. For more hints see [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) in our [Help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @Ayanoria another way to look at it - say you were to find distance covered between time period $\pi / 2$ to $3 \pi / 2$. What answer would you get if you simply used the domain as ($\pi / 2, 3 \pi / 2$)? It would be zero but the distance covered is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Given $v(t)=\mathrm{sin}\ t$, so $\int_{0}^{x} dx=\int_{0}^{t} \mathrm{sin}(t)dt$
$$x(t)=1-\mathrm{cos}\ t$$BUT, here $x(t)$ is the displacement.

Now, to find total distance you've to carefully check if ${x(t)}$ falls down from a value in the above equation, i.e. it definitely rises for t$\in(0,\pi)$ but after that, it starts falling.

[image]

Can you take it from here?